# Rails "Where" method - greater than (">") using endless ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, range

I just recently discovered a neat trick to replace greater than / less than in rails `where` in which you can use a range to replace the string version of where:

`Post.where('id <= ?', 10)`

can be replaced with:

`Post.where(id: ..10)`

and three dots changes it from `<=` to `<`

`Post.where('id < ?', 10)`

can be replaced with:

`Post.where(id: ...10)`

this trick seems to work for:

- less than or equal to `<=`
- less than `<`
- greater than or equal to `>=`

HOWEVER it does not work for greater than `>` because:

`Post.where(id: 10..)` and `Post.where(id: 10...)` will both search for greater than or equal to.

My question is, is there a way to get this to work for greater than (other than hacking it with `+ 1`?):

`Post.where(id: (10+1)..)`

My assumption is that the answer is no, but I still wanted to ask!

Here is a full example of what I am talking about:

```
Post.where(id: ..9)
=>   Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" <= $1  [["id", 9]]

Post.where(id: ...9)
=>   Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" < $1  [["id", 9]]

Post.where(id: 1..)
=>   Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" >= $1  [["id", 1]]

# NOTE: THIS STILL ONLY GOES >=, NOT > 
Post.where(id: 1...)
=>   Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" >= $1  [["id", 1]]
```

Comment: what version of Ruby are you using? I'm just getting syntax error for 2.6.3

Comment: @LesNightingill 2.7.3 - I believe the beginless `(..X)` and endless `(X..)` ranges were recently implemented to ruby

Comment: @LesNightingill the syntax introduced is actually just shorthand for `Float::INFINITY` so `1..` is the same as `1..Float::INFINITY`  and `..1` is the same a s `-Float::INFINITY..1` in older versions of ruby.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Today I learned...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `where.not`

```
Post.where.not(id: ..10).to_sql
# => SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" > 10
```

```
Post.where.not(id: ...10).to_sql
# => SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" >= 10
```

Note that `Post.where(id: (10+1)..)` works because the `id` is an integer column. However, this will not work for decimal columns, such as `Post.where('average_rating > 3.0')`. Using `Post.where(average_rating: (3.0+1)..)` will look for average ratings > 4 but skips posts with average rating of 3.5. `Post.where.not(average_rating: ..3.0)` will result in the correct query.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks. And yes, that's exactly why I didn't like the hack solution because it would not work with decimals or datetimes, etc.... it's unfornate that is is such an unreadable solution though. I did some other research and can conclude this is the way to do it... as of now at least - there have been several pull request attempts to improve `where` but till then, this is all we have :/  )Thanks again!!

Answer (score -1):

The main purpose of the question is trying to prevent having to change a long query into the "string" approach:

```
# good
Post.where(name: name, type: type, whatever: whatever)

# bad - uses string approach
Post.where('name = :name AND type = :type AND whatever = :whatever',
           name: name, type: type, whatever: whatever)
```

If greater than is needed, A way to get around this AND allow it to be readable, is to split the query into 2 separate where methods:

```
# good - only uses string approach with greater than which is more 
# readable that where.not
Post.where(name: name, type: type, whatever: whatever).where('id > ?', 10)

# bad - uses string method
Post.where('name = :name AND type = :type AND whatever = :whatever AND id > :id',
           name: name, type: type, whatever: whatever, id: 10)

# bad - where.not is not very readable
Post.where(name: name, type: type, whatever: whatever).where.not(id: ..10)
```