How can I update how ActiveRecord::Base#where interprets ranges?
It appears that ActiveRecord::Base#where partially distinguishes between ranges defined with 2 dots (0..) and ranges defined with 3 dots (0...).
E.g.
> User.where(id: ..0).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" <= 0"
> User.where(id: ...0).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" < 0"

Notice how the query defined with 3 dots use < compared to the query defined with 2 dots which uses <=.
This is a great feature, however, I've noticed this doesn't seem to be working with ranges with no top:
> User.where(id: 0..).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" >= 0"
> User.where(id: 0...).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" >= 0"

In this case, >= is used regardless of the number of dots.
I would like to submit a patch to the Rails gem to fix this, but I can't for the life of me figure out where this interpretation is happening.  I'm assuming it occurs somewhere in Arel, but so far I have not been able to find it.
If anyone can help guide me I would much appreciate it!

How would that change the behavior? … explicitly doesn’t include the range’s end value, and these don’t have an end value.

I don't how it works, I just know that it works.  I'm assuming once I find the code it will be clear how it differentiates.

this is by design https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/47345. you can use User.where.not(id: ..0) to generate >. this is the place you're looking for https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3.4/activerecord/lib/arel/predications.rb#L53

@gabeodess I’m asking what you think the bug is. There’s no range end value, the results are the same.

Ah, interesting, thank you @Alex!

@DaveNewton I guess I would expect User.where(id: 0...).to_sql to return "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" > 0" instead of using >=.

@gabeodess But that’s not what … does with ranges

@DaveNewton right, I'm seeing that after reviewing the links @Alex shared.
I would have expected ... to exclude both start and end, but to your point, Ruby defines it to only exclude end.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848908/rails-where-method-greater-than-using-endless-ranges

I would start by checking your Rails version and the issues on Rails. What you're encountering is most likely already been fixed.

Along with @Alex's post. Here is a much longer discussion on the topic: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40628

In interval terms, ranges in Ruby are always left-closed. The number of dots only determine if it's right-closed (..) or right-open (...). Ruby doesn't have the concept of left-open ranges (i.e. excluding the beginning).

Thank you @Alex for the explanation!
It looks like this is because Ruby defines a ... range to exclude the end of the range, but to includes the beginning of the range.
So in the case of ...0, zero is excluded resulting in <.
In the case of 0..., zero is included resulting in >=.
This is still counter-intuitive to me, but sounds like something I'd need to take up with the Ruby crew.

In Ruby ranges constructed with two dots include the value at the end while those with three exclude it:
(1..3).to_a == [1,2,3]
(1...3).to_a == [1,2]

Ranges with no start or end are called beginless or endless ranges.
(1..) and (1...) are not equal, although technically representing the same sequence. The same applies to beginless Ranges. Endless was introduced in Ruby 2.6 and beginless in Ruby 2.7.
How range options are implemented in the ActiveRecord Query Interface has very little to do with the actual Ruby Range class and is kind of arbitrary and strange as the concepts don't actually match up with LT, GT, LTE and GTE.
The support for the new range types showed up relatively late and were plagued by bugs until relatively recently.
While it's a nice convenience to be able to use endless/beginless you can construct those conditions with Arel instead:
User.where(User.arel_table[:id].lt(1))
User.where(User.arel_table[:id].lte(1))
User.where(User.arel_table[:id].gt(1))
User.where(User.arel_table[:id].gte(1))

While more wordy it's immediately apparent what the code actually does. In my book thats a win.

I'm too lazy to look up when Rails introduced endless/beginless and when the bugs that came with endless were fixed. If memory serves me right it was right after Rails 7.

FWIW endless ranges for ActiveRecord were introduced in 6.0 Release Notes and PR. beginless ranges in 6.1 PR and subsequently PR

Thanks @engineersmnky. You actually opened my eyes to how strange the "range syntax" is in the query interface.
